# How to lazy load headless ui Dialog in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, lazy-loading, headless-ui

I'm trying to lazy load a headless ui Dialog component but I haven't been able to do it while also keeping transitions.

Here's as close as I've gone:

```js
// Modal.js

const Modal = ({
  isOpen
}) => {
  return (
    <Transition show={isOpen}>
      <Dialog>
        ...
      </Dialog> 
    </Transition>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

```js
const Modal = lazy(() => import("~/components/Modal"));

<Suspense>
  {isOpen ? <Modal isOpen={isOpen} ... />
</Suspense>
```

This works for the most part but I lose the transition when the component is unmounted since `isOpen` is false then it gets unmounted immediately. But If I remove it then the component isn't lazy loaded when I open it but instead it loads on page load.

Is there a way to lazy load it while keeping the Transitions?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I faced a similar situation in the last days, but i would be very interested in other ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have 2 flags, one for the modal `open` state, and the second for the modal `visible` state

then we can add an effect that "listens" to changes in the `open` state, and adds `transitionend` event listener on the modal element when the `open` state changes to `false`,
we will set the event callback to change the `visible` state of the modal to `false` and it will be triggered once the transition is ended

You can see an example here:
[image: Edit gifted-rain-zpz2p7]

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to split up the modal into a container and the actual content via render props. This way only the necessary parts of the modal would be rendered on initial load of the page. The content logic wouldn't get rendered until the user decides to open the modal.

[image: Edit nervous-sun-vgsmmc]

**Modal.tsx**

```js
type ModalProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: VoidFunction;
  renderTitle?: () => ReactNode;
  renderContent: (config: { onClose: VoidFunction }) => ReactNode;
};

export function Modal({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  renderContent,
  renderTitle
}: ModalProps) {
  return (
    <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog as="div" onClose={onClose}>
        <Dialog.Panel>
          <Dialog.Title>{renderTitle?.()}</Dialog.Title>
          {renderContent({ onClose })}
        </Dialog.Panel>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
  );
}
```

```
const ModalContent = lazy(() => import("./modal-content"));

<Modal
  isOpen={isOpen}
  onClose={closeModal}
  renderTitle={() => <span>Title</span>}
  renderContent={(props) => (
    <Suspense>
      <ModalContent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  )}
/>
```

```
function ModalContent({ onClose }: { onClose: VoidFunction }) {
  console.log(`Render ${ModalContent.name}`);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi, Text!</p>

      <button type="button" onClick={onClose}>
        Got it, thanks!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```